# Does anyone see anything wrong with this? Mysql+PHP Error

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm running the following line :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags 
                SET tag = '".$onesearch."',  
                SET date = '".date('d-m-Y')."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

...and its dieing saying this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET date = '29-08-2010'' at line 1

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What is the field type for the date column?

Comment: table: date

columns : 

id (int11) (auto inc)
tag (varchar 20)
date (varchar 11)

Comment: Not the source of the syntax error, but you should know that MySQL does not accept date literals in DD-MM-YYYY format.  Only YYYY-MM-DD and YY-MM-DD.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove second `SET` from your insert query. it should like be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags 
                SET tag = '".$onesearch."',  
                date = '".date('d-m-Y')."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Congrats and +1 -- I had never seen that `SET` clause in `INSERT` (a mysql-special way to duplicate standard SQL's `INTO` and `VALUES`, which every other engine supports _as_ does mysql!-), so I deleted my A that specified `INTO` and `VALUES` instead (but it looks like @OMG may not want to delete his, possibly in defense of avoiding wanton, useless use of non-standard SQL constructs when perfectly good equivalent standard ones are available, I guess-).

Comment: @Alex Martelli  yes agreed. Different databse vendors ANSI implementations confuse end users. May be MySQL team REUSES update statement:). One advantage atleast I feel is that it is easy for developers to write this query instead of INSERT-VALUES if your number of columns are more than 7.

Answer (score 4):

Invalid syntax, you should only use one SET:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags 
            SET tag = '".$onesearch."',  
            date = '".date('d-m-Y')."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

And that is valid INSERT syntax, just an FYI (in response to one of the other answers).

Answer (score 3):

Are you able to output the query that is actually being run?  It could be that the tag contains a single quote, which escapes the closing quote & causes problems...  Which is why you'd want to use:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags 
                SET tag = '". mysql_real_escape_string($onesearch) ."',  
                    date = '".date('d-m-Y')."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Which is it you're trying to do here?
You start with `INSERT` syntax, but after the table reference convert to using `UPDATE` syntax.

### INSERT

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags 
               (tag, date) 
             VALUES 
               ('".$onesearch."', '".date('d-m-Y')."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

### UPDATE

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tags 
                SET tag = '".$onesearch."',  
                    date = '".date('d-m-Y')."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

...but you'll get records in the table to those two values.  You'd want a `WHERE` clause on that...

Comment: The OP's UPDATE type syntax is valid INSERT syntax, just has too many SET words in it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html  See the second example.

Comment: @permiso: News to me, thx.  I'd still avoid using that syntax for sake of the confusion.

Comment: Oops -- I had answered the same, but `mysql` **does** support a `SET` clause in `INSERT`, and @Adeel has it right, it's just the _repetition_ of `SET` that's an error.  So +1 to her, and I deleted my A (and I recommend the same course to you!-).

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I would agree with you there :)

Comment: And besides, UPDATE doesn't accept two SET keywords either.  :)

Comment: @Bill Karwin: Thx - corrected.  I clearly need to get some sleep

Answer (score 2):

i think your question was already answered by the others. but you should take care of that $onesearch variable. if it's not properly sanitized, a quote in it could break your code as well. if you are not doing it already, you should consider using `mysql_real_escape_string()` to protect you from errors and sql injection.